# regex: find all occurences of a specific number in a string

Tags: python, regex

In python, I would like to find all exact occurrences of the number 33 in this string and replace it with another number.

My input string is:

```
original = '33 he3333llo 331 42 I\'m a 32 string 30 33 a33a 33\n 33'
```

and my desired output is:

```
' NUMERO he3333llo 331 42 I\'m a NUMERO string 30 NUMERO a NUMERO a NUMERO \n NUMERO '
```

Here all occurrences of 33 (but not 3333, and 331) has been replaced with the placeholder ' NUMERO '.

I have tried by using:

```
NUMERIC_PATTERN = re.compile(r'([^\d]+?)%s([^\d]+?)'%(33),re.UNICODE|re.DOTALL )
original = '33 he3333llo 331 42 I\'m a 32 string 30 33 a33a 33\n 33'
print original
print re.findall(NUMERIC_PATTERN,original)
print re.sub(NUMERIC_PATTERN,r'\1 NUMERO \2', original)
```

Which gives "almost" the correct answer:

```
'33 he3333llo 331 42 I\'m a 32 string 30  NUMERO  a NUMERO a  NUMERO \n 33'
```

However, the first and the last 33 are not matched.

I thought this new expression should fix it but it doesn't (I include beginning and end of line as alternatives but it has the same result the first version):

```
NUMERIC_PATTERN2 = re.compile(r'([^\d^]+?)%s([^\d$]+?)'%(33),re.UNICODE|re.DOTALL )
```

Can anybody explain why NUMERIC_PATTERN2 does not work and suggest the solution?
(I would prefer a solution which uses standard re module in python)

Comment: Ah well, no answer doing explaining... I'll leave that here then: `[^\d^]` does not mean "match anything except beginning of line or digits", it means "match anything except digits or `^`. Same for `[^\d$]` where `^` and `$` are no more line anchors, but literal characters. Alternatively, you could use the same code but with the regex: `([^\d]|^)%s([^\d]|$)` (quantifiers shouldn't be needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!\d)33(?!\d)
```

Try this.    See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/18